# How to filter data from Core Data in iOS Using Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have an entity named **Student** which has the following structure:

[image]

I am fetching data from CoreData as :

```
 NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
 NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Student"];
 self.arrStudents = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
```

Now I want only those students which have `rollNum = 1001`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Try this`

```
**Objective C**

NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Student"];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"rollNum = %@", @"1001"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
self.arrStudents = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

**Swift** 
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = managedObjectContext
var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Student")
var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "rollNum = %@", "1001")
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
arrStudents = try? managedObjectContext?.fetch(fetchRequest)
```

Comment: how to predicate with multiple values in coredata, Ex: rollNum = 1001, 1002

Answer (score 1):

You should use `NSPredicate` to filter your results:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"rollNum == %d", 1001];
```